# OWASP BDD Security Test Automation causing SSO issue

Tags: selenium, owasp

I have SSO expiration problem while running BDD Security Test Automation scripts. I downloaded the OWASP BDD Security test automation code from GitHub and customized it for our web application. I am using Selenium with Java, Fiddler and OWASP ZAP to execute test scripts on the web application. The browser I am using is Firefox version 45. My web app using SSO for login.

I haven't configured the browser to auto logon. So when the script runs, the script would first do a SSO login and then take me to the app home page. The problem here is as soon as the script does the SSO login and tries to open the Home page of the application, the SSO is getting expired and the application doesn't display any GUI elements apart from the top banner.

In my corporate environment, the network connection happens through a automatic  configuration script that I set in the IE browser. I configured fiddler as a outgoing proxy in ZAP tool. I did some reading on the Internet but I don't understand much on how the whole interaction is happening from fiddler/ZAP . I was told that as we have a automatic config script in IE, we need to use fiddler. Please help me understand this.

I am working with the developer on this issue but till now we could not find out the root cause of it. We suspect that the call is happening through fiddler and ZAP to the server and something is going wrong in the middle causing SSO to expire.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks
Gauri